# How to query dynamoDb table attribute(not a partition key or sort key)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that has:

> userId(partition key) postId(sort key) category

I want to show all items filtered by category?

How should I do it?

My try

```
    const params = {
    TableName: "posts_reddit",

    KeyConditionExpression: "userId = :userId",
    FilterExpression: "category: category",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {

        ":userId": event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
        ":category":  "engineering"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a colon in your filter expression, it should be:

`"FilterExpression: "category: :category"`

The structure for the `ExpressionAttributeValues` is not right as well, you must provide which type you're passing as an argument. See ether example in the [scan operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property) docs.